# How to prioritize decryption on older MacBook Pro?

Tags: mac, high-sierra, filevault

I'm working on a 2011 MacBook Pro, and the decryption process is taking forever. It seems that it speeds up if I click on the System Preferences window. Is there a way to prioritize the process using 'renice' or something?

The drive is definitely showing its age; it's very sluggish.

Thoughts?

Comment: Encryption, or decryption? If it's the original hard drive, I would be looking to replace it with an SSD, as it's likely to fail at any time.

Comment: I'm trying to decrypt, because the owner wants to keep using it until it dies, and in my experience, FileVault isn't trustworthy. She bought a new M1 MacBook Air as well, so this older machine is not a priority. I just wondered how to prioritize the decryption process to get 'er done!